# Chrome interpreting jpg resource as Document

Tags: image, google-chrome, mime-types

Consider the following image at:
http://znood.com/images/801/130x130.jpg

I have a controller rendering this image and transferring it with image/jpeg MIME.

Chrome is throwing the warning:

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type
>   image/jpeg.

Why would an image be interpreted as a document and why would Chrome throw such a warning?

Comment: I saw this error when `filename` in the `Content-Disposition` had a comma in it. The solution was simply adding quotes around the filename.

Comment: Oddly enough, IE didn't have the problem. Moral of the story: always add quotes to avoid arbitrary file names from breaking headers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add the proper doctype to your pages, something like

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

and then start your HTML with

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Regards,

M.

Comment: The file I'm rendering is a jpeg

Comment: That doesn't matter. Browser use the doctype also to decide how to manage streamed contents. Moreover playin' with the doctype for example, may drive IE to use compatibility mode or not, and many many other stuffs. If you're referencing your jpg through a CSS there may event be other minor stuffs. Just for being sure, how do you reference the image? via a <img src=""> tag or using some other way ?

Comment: I'm using this image in meta for Facebook opengraph 

<meta property="og:image" content="http://znood.com/images/22/130x130.jpg" />

I'm using <!DOCTYPE html> for HTML5 and <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

Is there a way to keep these while still supporting HTML5 ?

Comment: Facebook APIs are completely unknown to me. Sorry, I guess I cannot help you. Just a simple suggestion, tag your question with Facebook and API, maybe some developer will come and give a proper answer. Regards.

Comment: Okay... Your post helped me figure out why I was getting the warnings: I was "inspecting" the image, this is why it was being interpreted as a "document". I wasn't getting the error in the page. Thanks :-)